# Não consigo subir aquivo para o servidor

Tags: php

Estou tentando subir um arquivo para o servidor (PDF) e o mesmo não sobe. Ná pagina que é para enviar o arquivo, quando clico em enviar não acontece nada.

Código da página onde é enviado o arquivo:

```
<?php
require_once("elementos.php");
?>
                <div class="alinha">
                <h3>Licitações</h3>
                <form action="cadastralicitacao.php" method="post">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Objeto</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="objeto" rows="4"></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Modalidade</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="modalidade">
                      <option value="Pregão">Pregão</option>
                      <option value="Concorrência">Concorrência</option>
                      <option value="Carta convite">Carta convite</option>
                      <option value="Tomada de preços">Tomada de preço</option>
                      <option value="Leilão">Leilão</option>
                      <option value="Chamamento">Chamamento</option>
                      <option value="Dispensa">Dispensa</option>
                      <option value="Inexigibilidade">Inexigibilidade</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputFile">Status do processo</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="status">
                      <option value="Em andamento">Em andamento</option>
                      <option value="Encerrado">Encerrado</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Número do processo</label>
                      <input type="text" name="numprocesso" class="form-control" placeholder="Forneça o número do processo">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Data de abertura</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dataabertura" placeholder="Forneça o número do processo">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <form method="post" action="recebe_upload.php" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
                      <input type="hidden" name="enviou" value="1">
                      <label>Arquivo</label>
                      <input type="file" name="arquivo" />
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 <?php
 require_once("rodape.php");
```

Código em PHP:

```
<?php 
require_once "funcoes.php";

$msg = false;

if( isset($_POST['enviou']) && $_POST['enviou'] == 1 ){

    // arquivo
    $arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];

    // Tamanho máximo do arquivo (em Bytes)
    $tamanhoPermitido = 1024 * 1024 * 2; // 2Mb

    //Define o diretorio para onde enviaremos o arquivo
    $diretorio = "uploads/";

    // verifica se arquivo foi enviado e sem erros
    if( $arquivo['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){

        // pego a extensão do arquivo
        $extensao = extensao($arquivo['name']);

        // valida a extensão
        if( in_array( $extensao, array("pdf") ) ){

            // verifica tamanho do arquivo
            if ( $arquivo['size'] > $tamanhoPermitido ){

                $msg = "<strong>Aviso!</strong> O arquivo enviado é muito grande, envie arquivos de até ".$tamanhoPermitido/MB." MB.";
                $class = "alert-warning";

            }else{

                // atribui novo nome ao arquivo
                $novo_nome  = md5(time()).".".$extensao;

                // faz o upload
                $enviou = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome);

                if($enviou){
                    $msg = "<strong>Sucesso!</strong> Arquivo enviado corretamente.";
                    $class = "alert-success";
                }else{
                    $msg = "<strong>Erro!</strong> Falha ao enviar o arquivo.";
                    $class = "alert-danger";
                }
            }

        }else{
            $msg = "<strong>Erro!</strong> Somente arquivos PDF são permitidos.";
            $class = "alert-danger";
        }

    }else{
        $msg = "<strong>Atenção!</strong> Você deve enviar um arquivo.";
        $class = "alert-info";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Mas ocorre alguma mensagem de erro das que você usou nas IFs ou fica uma tela em "branco" ou algum erro HTTP?

Comment: Não, nao acontece nada, eis o problema

Comment: Não acontece nada é bem vago, quando vc clica no botão pra alguma página ele deve ir né? é claro que vc não tá sabendo explicar direito, de qualquer forma já achei o problema, olha a resposta.

Comment: Exclui minha resposta, depois de tantas edições, só agora vi o código completo e os dois forms, e quando respondi o Guilherme respondeu junto.

Comment: @FernandoVR por isso que responder perguntas vagas dá dores de cabeça, o ideial é orientar o autor a ler o MCVE: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - assim evita estes problemas.

Comment: É verdade @GuilhermeNascimento, é q para mim a primeira edição da pergunta dele parecia um problema simples. Nesse caso não era nem que estava vaga, mas ele postou o código dele incompleto. kkk Mas pega nada.

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que FORM **não pode ir** dentro FORM:

```
        <!-- form fora --->
    <form action="cadastralicitacao.php" method="post">
      ...
      <div class="form-group">

        <!-- form dentro --->
        <form method="post" action="recebe_upload.php" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
          <input type="hidden" name="enviou" value="1">
          <label>Arquivo</label>
          <input type="file" name="arquivo" />
        </form>
        <!-- form dentro --->

      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
    </form>
        <!-- form fora --->

  </div>
```

Ou seja se fizer isso:

```
<form>
    <form>
    </form>
</form>
```

Não vai funcionar, mas se fizer isso vai:

```
<form>
</form>

<form>
</form>
```

Tire o form de dentro do outro e mais um detalhe, o form de upload não pode usar `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, ele deve usar `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Isso funcionou, porém o arquivo nao ta aparecendo na pasta, ele nao sobe

Comment: @PedroRibeiro tá mas em qual if ele cai quando você conclui o upload? Cai no `Sucesso!`?

Comment: }else{

                // atribui novo nome ao arquivo
                $novo_nome  = md5(time()).".".$extensao;

                // faz o upload
                $enviou = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome);

                if($enviou){
                    $msg = "<strong>Sucesso!</strong> Arquivo enviado corretamente.";
                    $class = "alert-success";

Comment: @PedroRibeiro eu não to pedindo código, eu to perguntando em qual if "ele entra" quando você envia o POST.

Comment: Talvez esteja com problema na função que ele está utilizando pra pegar a extensão do arquivo. Creio q se ele mudar a linha: `$extensao = extensao($arquivo['name']);` para `$extensao = pathinfo($arquivo['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` pode resolver um dos problemas. E tbm é preciso verificar se a pasta upload existe e se o caminho está correto, se não vai dar erro tbm.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$msg' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\painelnovo\pages\recebe_upload.php on line 5

Comment: Esse erro eu arrumei, agora tá acusando erro nessa linha:     $arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];    
Notice: Undefined index: arquivo in C:\xampp\htdocs\painelnovo\pages\recebe_upload.php on line 10

Comment: deu certo aqui ja, obrigado a todos que me ajudaram